# Add a character into a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript:

- I have a string: `12345`
- I want a string: `12.345`

How do I add a character into a specific position in a string? I could split the string, add the "." and put them together or give the array out, but I´m sure there is a much better and quicker way.

Comment: Is your *real* question that you want to have thousands separators? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript — note that programming questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the string as an integer, then convert it to a decimal number like so:

```
function insertDecimal(num) {
   return (num / 100).toFixed(3);
}
```

*(Copied from nnnnnn's response: [Adding Decimal place into number with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524619/adding-decimal-place-into-number-with-javascript))*

I don't know what you need this for, but as for practical use, this would probably be the best way.